# How to display or do eDNS in dpdk packets?

Tags: c, dns, dpdk

I am using l2fwd-dpdk application from which I can extract 5-tuples, and can see if DNS Packet is present or not.

Now I want to classify the DNS Packet using dpdk, for which I am failing.
Here is my code.

```
 struct rte_udp_hdr *udp_hdr;
 struct dnshdr *dns_hdr;

 if (rte_be_to_cpu_16(udp_hdr->dst_port) == 53)
 {  
 printf("DNS Packet");
 char *dns_hdr = (char *)udp_hdr + sizeof(rte_udp_hdr);
 }
```

I want to separate

- Flags
- Rdata
- Class
- TTL

and save them separately. Is there any way around, I can comfortable to use cpp wrapper as well.

Comment: Please add the relevant structure definitions and/or header files to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DPDK as of 21.08 *does not house any header or structure to typecast to DNS packet*. Hence easiest way to solve the issue as mentioned by @wildplasser is to declare your custom DNS header and use it. In your code snippet, you already have `struct dnshdr *dns_hdr;` So the easier way is to modify your existing code to reflect

```
 struct rte_udp_hdr *udp_hdr;
 struct dnshdr *dns_hdr;

/* use DPDK mtod API to get the start of ethernet frame */
/* check for packet size, ether type, IP protocol */
/* update udp_hdr to position in the packet */

 if (rte_be_to_cpu_16(udp_hdr->dst_port) == 53)
 {  
 printf("DNS Packet");
 struct dnshdr *dns_hdr = (struct dnshdr *)((char *)udp_hdr + sizeof(rte_udp_hdr));
 }
```

Note: Possible structure definition code snippet would be

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t id;
    uint16_t rd:1;
    uint16_t tc:1;
    uint16_t aa:1;
    uint16_t opcode:4;
    uint16_t qr:1;
    uint16_t rcode:4;
    uint16_t zero:3;
    uint16_t ra:1;
    uint16_t qcount;    /* question count */
    uint16_t ancount;   /* Answer record count */
    uint16_t nscount;   /* Name Server (Autority Record) Count */ 
    uint16_t adcount;   /* Additional Record Count */
} custom_dnshdr;

custom_dnshdr *dns_hdr = (custom_dnshdr *) ((char *)udp_hdr + sizeof(rte_udp_hdr));
```